# Different Response to simulator vs skype integration

Tags: dialogflow-es, skype

[here is the image for better understanding, i merged the inline editor, simulator, and skype](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ZRKE.png)

I just created an agent and intent entity with sone parameters and in the fullfilment tab, in the inline editor wrote some code to give response specific to the intent parameter, while all this is working as expected in the simulator. But giving generic response(intent static response) in the Skype integration. Should i do anything extra for skype?

Why is the behaviour different?

Does it have anything to do with webhook?

Ps: I have enabled fullfilment for the intent

Comment: Can you update your question to show the code in question and screenshots of how it looks in the simulator?

Comment: Please check the question again, i added the link to requested image, thanks